# Comment form not working in Drupal 7.x

Tags: 7

Primary tabs

```
View(active tab)
Edit
```

**Status message**

Forum topic Comment form not working has been created.
Posted by jassics on February 8, 2014 at 9:49pm

I am facing problem in commenting over blog or forum contents.
It is simply showing this error:

**Error**

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

While checking error log I got this:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unable to get the data property format
>   as the parent data structure is not set. in
>   EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyValue() (line 438 of
>   /home6/cusatalu/public_html/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

and when I checked filedsets I saw these warnings

> Notice: Undefined index: comment_node_panel in
>   _field_ui_bundle_admin_path() (line 325 of /home6/cusatalu/public_html/modules/field_ui/field_ui.module). Notice:
>   Undefined index: comment_node_panel in field_ui_fields_list() (line 35
>   of /home6/cusatalu/public_html/modules/field_ui/field_ui.admin.inc).

Hope, someone is familiar with this error and would help me to fix soon.

I posted this in Drupal official site too.

Answer (score 0):

First problem see: https://drupal.org/node/1909078#comment-8718835

"While I could be mistaken, I'm pretty sure that the error regarding "Unable to get the data property format..." (note the emphasis on format) when inserting a comment is due to code in:

message_notify/plugins/notifier/abstract.inc

Specifically these lines:

```
// Get the format from the field. We assume the first delta is the
// same as the rest.
if (empty($wrapper->{$field_name}->format)) {
  $wrapper->{$field_name}->set($output[$view_mode]);
}
else {
  $format = $wrapper->type->{MESSAGE_FIELD_MESSAGE_TEXT}->get(0)->format->value();
  $wrapper->{$field_name}->set(array('value' => $output[$view_mode], 'format' => $format));
```

}

The error occurs in the "comment insert" message type for the field_message_rendered_body field (and not the field_message_rendered_subject field) since it's a textarea that by default allows filtered text types to be selected (i.e. in Managed Fields, select the rendered body field and you'll see "Filtered text (user selects text format)" checked under "Text processing"). I haven't investigated fully yet but the bug can be avoided by selecting "Plain text" under "text processing" in the meantime (which will bypass the empty $wrapper->type->{MESSAGE_FIELD_MESSAGE_TEXT}->get(0)->format->value() in the ELSE statement)."